# Select multiple lines for a PR review comment

Tags: github

Is it possible to select multiple seperate lines in a PR review comment on github? To be clear, I dont mean selecting a larger block, I mean entirely separate specific lines like, say, 50, 120, and 300 all have one comment that highlights them

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's still not possible.

You can upvote for the corresponding [feature request](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/5022).